# Multiple where clauses and elimination

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate the count of unique drivers who have completed their trip and never cancel on the client. If a driver has ever canceled on any client they should be removed from the results.

I'm wondering if a subquery is needed here or not. 
The data that I am working with is shown here and while rudimentary, it's simply to test my query.

```
id  driver_id   client_id   city_id status
1   1011        9004        546     completed
1   1011        9008        323     completed
2   1011        9001        546     completed
3   1011        9006        323     completed
3   1011        9007        154     cancelled_by_client
1   1012        9001        546     cancelled_by_client
2   1012        9003        123     cancelled_by_driver
2   1012        9002        789     completed
2   1013        9007        546     cancelled_by_driver
4   1013        9006        546     cancelled_by_driver
2   1015        9001        546     completed
3   1015        9006        323     completed
3   1015        9007        154     cancelled_by_client
```

What I am after as my expected result is a count of the unique driver IDs that have both completed their trips and never canceled on the client (canceled_by_driver).

```
driver_id    non_driver_cancels
1011         1
1015         1
```

I have a GROUP BY in here to show the data with more detail and I am seeing that driver 1012 has a canceled_by_driver but they are still in my results. From there I believe I can simply count the driver_id's and finish this task.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7cca/7

Comment: I am having trouble opening SQL Fiddle, so I cannot see your actual table name.

Comment: If you want the **count** of drivers, then you will need a subquery; otherwise, see Gordon's answer. ...if you want the count, the Gordon's answer IS the subquery, and you just need to count the distinct driver_id's of it's results.

Comment: Also, what about a possible driver that has only "cancelled_by_client" status values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select driver_id, sum(status = 'cancelled_by_client') as client_cancels
from t
group by driver_id
having sum(status = 'cancelled_by_driver') = 0;
```

This assumes that the only other type of  cancellation is "cancelled_by_client", as shown in your data.

Comment: As much as I don't like mysql, I do love that you can do boolean math in it. That would save so much typing.

Comment: Thank you very much. With this and @ueerdo s comment, I was able to create a query that works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT driver_id, COUNT( DISTINCT driver_id) as Non_Driver_Cancel
FROM Trip
WHERE status NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM Trip WHERE status <> 'cancelled_by_driver')
GROUP BY driver_id;
```